# how can I select the user's email to send an email?

Tags: laravel

the user will have a form where he will fill in the information and when executing the form he will make this code that sends an email, but I wanted that instead of being the one to receive it, I would like to know how I can make it become the email that the user put in the form to receive?

```
Mail::send('emails.checkout.mail', [
            'email' => $request->email,

            'total' => $total], function ($messagem) use ($request)  {

            $messagem->from('noreply@xxx.com', 'Noreply');

            $messagem->to('EMAIL OF USER')->subject('new menssage');

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mail::send('emails.checkout.mail', [
            'email' => $request->email,

            'total' => $total], function ($messagem) use ($request)  {

            $messagem->from('noreply@xxx.com', 'Noreply');

            $messagem->to($request->email)->subject('new menssage');

        });
```

Send it to $request->email